# ASP.Net User Authentication IE - Cached credentials

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, internet-explorer, active-directory

I have an ASP.net web application that’s running on our intranet, it is using active directory for authentication. We recently migrated away from an old domain to a new domain. Some users are getting This Page Cannot Be Displayed error when connecting to the application.

The errors seem to persist on IE 11 but works in Chrome or Firefox. I suspect that IE is caching user credentials and trying to log users on using their stored credentials and passwords.

We have tried clearing cache and cookies with mixed results, the server has also been restarted but the problems persist.

Any thoughts on how to address this and force IE to users the use their actual credentials and not cached credentials?

Not to add confusion, but I have had some success with some users connecting using the IIS webserver IP address rather than the qualified name e.g. 10.x.x.x/appname.aspx instead of MyServerName/appname.aspx

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suspect for those users with the problem that they have allowed IE to save their password.  That is not in a cookie.

Have a look in Credential Manager on their workstations.  Depending on the OS it would be:  Control Panel\User Accounts\Credential Manager

Click "Web Credentials" and if there is a Web Password stored for your application, you will see the URL listed.  Just delete it.

This would also explain why the IP works.  Because the cached credential is tied to the URL.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tried this, but found that no web credentials are present on any of the users machines. Not sure if our IS policy has anything to do with this.